# textured filling circle

Tags: materials

It's a quick question.
I want to put the texture in the circle, but I can't see the texture of the image. But when I put the image in the same way on the plane, it is successful. Why not in circle?

I want to finally build a circular road. I want to add the texture of the road.

That's what it looks like in edit mode.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Could it be that your circle doesn't have a UV map?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the texture to show, you just need to unwrap the mesh. However, this will leave you with a square texture mapped to a ring, and it wont "follow the path" so to speak.

To do this, things are only a little more complicated. First, unwrap your mesh (`select all > U > unwrap`). Then go to the UV editing tab.

[image: Unwrap]

Select the two vertices at the top of one of the edges that is on the side (because it's side edge is perfectly vertical). Press <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>. This will make the two points at equal "height" on the y axis. Do this for both the top and bottom edges, so you're left with a rectangular shaped quad.

[image: UVTab]

Then, select the whole mesh, making sure the quad you created is the active face (lighter color). If you need to make it active, just un-select and re-select the face - just make sure all the faces are selected when you're done. With your mouse over the 3D view port (not the UV map), press <kbd>U</kbd> and select `Follow Active Quads`. Confirm in the box that pops up and your UV map will be straightened.

[image: FollowActive]

From there, just scale the UV island back to size and place it where you want in a the UV space. Add a texture and you're done.

[image: TextureReady]